# Suck with a nose

Tags: single-word-requests

What word is there in English for sucking with your nose? There are people who do not sneeze but instead have a bad habit of sucking with their nose snot in again. However, the English dictionary definition for sucking refers to the mouth.

Comment: Best post title of the week, in any case: +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not to steal your thunder joseph_morris, but while the act is a *sniffle* as a verb it would be to *sniff* or *snort*.

Edit-To expound slightly more, I found this [page for UK English slang](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/en/en/translate/snuffling), but it has a pretty expansive breakdown of *snuffling*.

Comment: I rather like the onomatapoeic *snork*. *Snort* is generally outwards; *snork* is exactly the sound of a snotty sniff.

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble, Abernasty, but "sniffle" is also an intransitive verb. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sniffle?show=0&t=1392319825

Comment: @Andrew: Agreed. *Snorking* is ***in** through the **nose***, contrasting with *hawking*, which is ***out** through the throat / **mouth***.

Comment: @Louel Ah, so it is. I guess I would say that anecdotally at least, I'm used to sniffle being used as a noun and sniff the verb, though they can both swap those parts of speech.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not sure I agree that *snort* is generally outwards, but if you're ever accused in the future of having a cocaine habit, you can reference your comment here as showing you don't even know how ;)

Comment: Since you're answering with reference to UK slang, maybe things are different on that side of the pond. But in the US "to sniff" is usually inhaling air audibly; "to snort" is to make a pig-like sound while inhaling (or to inhale drugs, esp. cocaine); and "to sniffle" involves inhaling snot. The question was about snot. So, I still say sniffle.

Comment: I agree with Joseph - at least this side of the pond, sniffing means breathing air into your nose with the purpose of smelling something, sniffling means breathing air into your nose with the purpose of dislodging snot. (And snort is of course breathing air into your nose with the purpose of inhaling some sort of recreational drug - I'm not sure I've ever seen it in any other capacity. :p)

Comment: In my experience of Australian English, "sniffle" is not something I ever hear; "Sniff" carries the day in almost all cases.

Answer (score 3):

The word you're looking for is "sniffle."

Answer (score 1):

Or try the word "snuffle": :  to snuff especially audibly and repeatedly

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snuffle

Comment: Doesn't snuffing require the use of snuff?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly: Insufflate

Insufflation (Latin insufflatio "blowing on" or "into") is the practice of inhaling a substance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insufflation_(medicine)

http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/insufflation

Answer (score 0):

Oxford Dictionaries gives as the meaning of 'sniff': 'draw up air audibly through the nose to detect a smell, to stop it running, or to express contempt'.

There is also a verb 'sniffle'meaning: 'sniff slightly or repeatedly, typically because of a cold or fit of crying'.

Comment: I am not aware of it happening in humans, but dogs will occasionally "sneeze backward."